# Javascript strings not supporting special characters

Tags: javascript, string, hta

I have an HTA with 3 frames which overall looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function f(){
          frames["toolbar"].document.write("Toolbar");
          frames["statusbar"].document.write("Status bar");
     }
</script>
<frameset rows="65,*,19" onload="f()">
     <frame src="about:blank" name="toolbar" application="yes"/>
     <frame src="url.html" name="main" application="yes"/>
     <frame src="about:blank" name="statusbar" application="yes"/>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Note: The content of the toolbar and statusbar frames are more complicated than what's specified here.

Notice that two frames are defined using JavaScript and don't have a real URL.

Since this HTA is in Swedish, i need to use Swedish special letters which are å, ä and ö, for example `alert("Du är inte uppkopplad")`. The problem is that in the toolbar frame and in the statusbar frame which the content has been defined in JavaScript, this alert box looks like this:
[image]

It replaces ä with an ugly square in the toolbar frame and in the statusbar frame, but not in the main frame (which has a real URL). How do I fix this?

Comment: Use a proper editor and convert from ANSI to `UTF8`. Also you can add a meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Then the encoding in which the file containing the `ä` is submitted is different to the one used to create the `ä`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I create a variable in the parent HTA which takes the value`ä` like this:

Main HTA:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function f(){
          frames["toolbar"].document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'><\/script>");
          frames["statusbar"].document.write("Status bar");
     }
     var a = "ä"
</script>
<frameset rows="65,*,19" onload="f()">
     <frame src="about:blank" name="toolbar" application="yes"/>
     <frame src="url.html" name="main" application="yes"/>
     <frame src="about:blank" name="statusbar" application="yes"/>
</frameset>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
alert("Du " + parent.a + "r inte uppkopplad");
```

Thanks to t.niese for giving me the idea in a comment.